# How can we transfer data between classes when using swift programming language

Tags: swift, class, data-transfer

With Objective-C we could transfer data to an array at an UIView class from ViewController using a method.

In an UIView class we were using something like this

```
 float values[10];

-(void) getValue:(float) value index:(int) index {

    values[index] = value       

   }
```

But when we try doing a similar thing with Swift such as

```
    var values   : [CGFloat] = [10]

       func getValue (value:CGFloat, index:Int) {

       values [index] = value

    }
```

We are getting  " fatal error: Array index out of range error " or if we use

```
       var values   : [CGFloat] = [10]
       var index = 0

       func getValue (value:CGFloat) {

       values.append = value

       ++index
    }
```

We are not getting error message but whenever we use setNeedsDisplay()  array values are being set to initial values which is 10 for this example.

Till now we are unable to convert Objective-C UIView classes like that to Swift one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after studying some more Swift I found the answer to my question.

Using static variable in the UIView class is the answer.

Define variable like that in UIView class

```
struct StructToChange {

  static  var varToChange = 1

}
```

Write a function to change variable value like this in UIView class.

```
func getIt (newValue:Int) {

    StructToChange.varToChange = newValue

}
```

Call the function in a controller class this way

```
  let valueChanger = AnyUIViewClass()
  valueChanger.getIt ( 10 )
```

This is it you changed the value of variable and you can use it as parameter in your " override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {  }  "

Comment: keep reading and learning. In a comment to my answer, you wrote that you found a solution without using a global variable... The above solution uses a global variable. I'm glad it works for you and hope that one day you figure out what the real problem was.

Comment: Thanks, but what I understood is there haven't been a problem actually. At Swift when a normal variable has been used every time UIView class variable has been called a new variable have been created and new one was with default value. Even if a function is called to change variable value, it could not been changed. As a matter of fact I checked it inside of function with print and it is seemed changed with success but outside it was the default value again. This is a different behavior than Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

First:

`var values   : [CGFloat] = [10]`

That line says that `values` is a variable array of CGFloat values that currently holds a single value of `10`. Therefore, only index 0 actually exists.

Also:

```
func getValue(value:CGFloat, index:Int) {
    values [index] = value
}
```

Never mind the fact that you have put this on the UIView class, never mind that you have a method named "getValue" that actually sets a value...

**EDIT:**

I found a better solution:

```
var values = Array<Float>(count:10, repeatedValue: 0)

func getValue(value: Float, index: Int) {
    values[index] = value
}
```

The above is the direct Swift equivalent to the Objective-C code you posted in your question.

Frankly, I think you should take a step back and find a better way to solve the problem you think this code is solving. As it stands it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: You are right, that does not make any sense, because when aView.setNeedsDisplay() executed for the class all the values are being removed from the array contrary to Obj-C and we can not draw anything and that is the question.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay() will not remove any values from your array unless you explicitly override the function and remove them. Sorry, but I think you don't really understand what is happening, even in the original Obj-C code.

Comment: Maybe it was my mistake but the question was not about finding similar way to define an array variable in Swift. It is about copying an array from a controller class to an UIView class. We could do it in objective-c by using a method which was in UIView class and  was using this array of values to draw things but now, in Swift whenever setNeedsDisplay() executed values copied from controller class erased and default array values being loaded hence no requested drawings.

Comment: Again, setNeedsDisplay is not going to erase anything in your global array. There must be something else happening.

Comment: It was not a "Global" so that must be the key. Because it was not global at Obj_C and was working just fine we did not make it global in Swift as well.

Comment: Even it it isn't a global, setNeedsDisplay will not affect that variable in any way, unless you explicitly override the method and add code that affects the variable. I really think there is something else going on that you haven't accounted for or don't understand. Would you consider a code review?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I found a solution without using global variable etc. Check my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values : [CGFloat] = [10]
```

In swift, this will create an array of CGFloat with one element: 10.0, not 10 elements. 
so values.count is one

[Swift Collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)